# Maven war overlay with Alfresco AMP

Tags: maven, overlay, alfresco, maven-war-plugin

According to this [article](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public/alfresco-lifecycle-aggregator/latest/plugins/alfresco-maven-plugin/advanced-usage.html), it should be possible to use Alfresco Module Package (AMP) as an overlay (it seems to be a plain .zip file)

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <overlays>
          <overlay/>
          <overlay>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <excludes/>
          </overlay>
          <overlay>
            <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
            <artifactId>alfresco-wcm-quickstart-repo</artifactId>
            <type>amp</type>
          </overlay>
        </overlays>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.e</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.alfresco</groupId>
    <artifactId>alfresco-wcm-quickstart-repo</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.e</version>
    <type>amp</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I get the following warning message when packaging the war:

```
[WARNING] Skip unpacking dependency file [C:\Users\svorc\.m2\repository\org\alfresco\alfresco-wcm-quickstart-repo\4.0.e\alfresco-wcm-quickstart-repo-4.0.e.amp with unknown extension [amp]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you inheriting from the parent pom supplied by the Maven Alfresco SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `mvn integration-test -Pamp-to-war`

And be sure to have the following in you parent:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </parent>
```